# Doing time subtraction with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two time values on a page:

```
8:00
22:30
```

I need to subtract 8 from 22:30 and get 14:30.

Is there a straight forward way to do that in jQuery?  Plug-ins are fine by me if they're necessary.

**Update**: 
The second number is a grand total so it could also be something like

```
48:45
```

Anything I subtract from it should just subtract the value from it as a total, not do any date related calculations.

Comment: do you need to be able to overnight?

Comment: No overnight...the second value is always a grand total of hours.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it in javascript.

Suppose you have `start = '8:00'` and `end = '22:30'`. The code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var start = '8:00';
    var end = '23:30';

    s = start.split(':');
    e = end.split(':');

    min = e[1]-s[1];
    hour_carry = 0;
    if(min < 0){
        min += 60;
        hour_carry += 1;
    }
    hour = e[0]-s[0]-hour_carry;
    diff = hour + ":" + min;

    alert(diff);
</script>
```

In the end, `diff` is your time difference.

Comment: Thanks for solution, but would you test start: 6:00 and end: 1:30 ? it returns -5 in hour...

Answer (score 2):

i think try this code -:

```
 var start = '8:00';
 var end = '23:30';

var startDate = new Date("1/1/1900 " + start _time);
var endDate = new Date("1/1/1900 " + end );
var difftime=endDate - startDate; //diff in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery isn't required, you can do it in straight JavaScript with something simple like:

```
function timeInHours(str)
{
   var sp = str.split(":");
   return sp[0] + sp[1]/60;
}

function hoursToString(h)
{
   var hours = floor(h);
   var minutes = (h - hours)*60;

   return hours + ":" + minutes;
}

var time1 = "08:00";
var time2 = "22:30";

var tot = hoursToString(timeInHours(time2) - timeInHours(time1));
```

Comment: I would have gone with `timeInMinutes` and `minutesToString`, only to preference integer operations over floats.

Answer (score 0):

jquery doesnt have any date parsing/manipulation built in. I also havent seen many plugins for that.
Your best bet would be to create a function that converts the two dates into ints, do the addition, and then turn the result into a date.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [Timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm after but thanks for pointing it out.