# Time difference in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to subtract two 24-hour time values from 0 to 23 using JQuery.

e.g. , 01:00 - 03:00 should return 22:00 hours

but my function's not working

```
function TimeDiff()
{
    var start=$('#fTime').val();    
    var end = '03:00';
    var diff=(start-end+24)%24;
    $('#bReg').val(diff);   
}
```

Do I need to do some sort of conversion to Time object or ...?

Any ideas? `^..^`

Comment: A `String` doesn't magically become a `Date` object :P

Comment: You need to either create actual `Date`s, or convert the hours/minutes to numbers and do the math manually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053057/doing-time-subtraction-with-jquery

Comment: The [MDN page on Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) has an example of calculating elapsed time between two dates.

Comment: there is Date object. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519887/jquery-time-difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this demo please, i wrote a demo for you, you can use it;

http://jsfiddle.net/BSeN6/2/

Comment: Thanks erimerturk! It's Working fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
var diff =
    new Date( '01/01/2009 ' + $('#fTime').val()) -
    new Date( '01/01/2009 ' + "03:00 PM" );

var hours=(diff / 1000)+"";//just to make it a string
```

use `hours+":00"` for outputs like "22:00" hrs
Also, find the time format should have a AM/PM

Comment: when i enter 23:00 it gives me 28:80 code `  function TimeDiff()
   {
    var start=$('#fTime').val(); 
 
    var diff =new Date( '01/01/2009 ' + $('#fTime').val())-new Date( '01/01/2009 ' + "03:00 PM" );
   
    var hours=(diff / 1000)+"";  
    var mins=(diff / 1000 / 60 )+"";
    
    var diff_time=hours+":"+mins;  
   
   
    $('#bReg').val(diff_time); 
   }`