# calculate time difference in HH:mm format

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have two timestamps in `HH:mm` format and I need to calculate difference between them representing the time interval in the same `HH:mm` format.

Is there any utility in JavaScript to achieve this? I tried using `Date` object, but I cannot find something useful... Can you help me?

Comment: please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976655/time-difference-in-jquery

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can just substract two Dates from one another, the result will be the difference in milliseconds.

From the [Mozilla Developer Network:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Example:_Calculating_elapsed_time)

```
// using static methods
var start = Date.now();
// the event you'd like to time goes here:
doSomethingForALongTime();
var end = Date.now();
var elapsed = end - start; // time in milliseconds
```

Since Date has a constructor that accepts milliseconds as an argument, you can re-convert this to a Date by just doing

```
var difference = new Date(elapsed);
//If you really want the hours/minutes, 
//Date has functions for that too:
var diff_hours = difference.getHours();
var diff_mins = difference.getMinutes();
```

Comment: How can I parse a `HH:mm` string to a `Date` object?

Comment: Have you read the MDN Date API? There are a lot of ways, but two spring to mind: use the `new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond])` constructor, or create a new Date and use `setHours` & `setMinutes`.

Comment: How do i get time diffrence between date = "2016/03/01 11:00" to date ="2016/03/06 11:00"

Comment: I recommend using getUTCHours() and getUTCMinutes() instead, in order to handle timezone issues.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
​var t1 = '12:04'.split(':'), t2 = '3:45'​​​​​​​.split(':');
var d1 = new​ Date(0, 0, 0, t1[0], t1[1]),
    d2 = new Date(0, 0, 0, t2[0], t2[1]);
var diff = new Date(d1 - d2);
```

Comment: i prefer something like this

`code`
var t1 = jstart.split(":");
            var t2 = jstop.split(":");

            var min_1 = parseInt(t1[0]) * 60 + parseInt(t1[1]);
            var min_2 = parseInt(t2[0]) * 60 + parseInt(t2[1]);

            console.log((min_2-min_1));
`code`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

https://github.com/layam/js_humanized_time_span

and format the output?

or if using jquery you can try

http://timeago.yarp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming tim1 is a string like "09:15" and tim2 is a string like "19:05", then the difference between tim2 and tim1 could be derived with the following javascript code :-

```
var tim1='09:15',tim2='19:05';
var ary1=tim1.split(':'),ary2=tim2.split(':');
var minsdiff=parseInt(ary2[0],10)*60+parseInt(ary2[1],10)-parseInt(ary1[0],10)*60-parseInt(ary1[1],10);
alert(String(100+Math.floor(minsdiff/60)).substr(1)+':'+String(100+minsdiff%60).substr(1));
```