# Using jQuery to calculate the difference between 2 HTML5 time fields

Tags: jquery, html, datetime

I would like to use jQuery to work out the difference between two times using HTML5 time.

So for example I get two times with a format such as 16:07 and 18:06. I'd like to work out the difference in hours and minutes between the two times so that I can use that value in another HTML5 time field. It is assumed that the two times take place on the same day so that is not an issue.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Unfortunately maths is not my strongest point so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193342/calculate-time-difference-in-hhmm-format?

Comment: Have you tried anything?