# Calculate the difference between two dates and give the result in hh:mm format

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
date1=2023-01-02T12:22:00
date2=2023-01-03T22:15:00
```

How could I found the time difference?

Comment: What data structure / form / units do you want to result to be in?

Comment: @Arindam Panda check the solution from my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function secondsToHMS(secs) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}
  var sign = secs < 0 ? '-' : '';
  secs = Math.abs(secs);
  return sign + z(secs/3600 |0) + ':' + z((secs%3600) / 60 |0);
}

var d1 = new Date('2023-01-03T22:15:00');
var d2 = new Date('2023-01-02T12:22:00');

//console.log( secondsToHMS((d1 - d2) / 1000)); // 33:53
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12193371/9067107

The steps are firstly converting the UTC time via `new Date()` and calculate the different by `date1 - date2` and get the Hours / Minutes different.

Lets assume you want to have HH:mm format in string

```
let date1 = new Date('2023-01-02T12:22:00')
let date2 = new Date('2023-01-03T22:15:00')
let diff = new Date(date2 - date1)
let diffInHoursMinutes = `${diff.getHours()}:${diff.getMinutes()}`
```

Comment: This is not worked! It only calculates the difference between two times. But we need the difference between two whole days.