# How to subtract time slot in jquery?

Tags: javascript, time

I try this code

```
start_time = '08:15 AM'
end_time = '03:45 PM'
diff = end_time - start_time;
```

only i want to subtract time in jquery. I have tried same in php as follow and it is running properly. 
but not in jquery

```
$st = strtotime("07:30 AM");
$edt = strtotime("06:15 AM");
echo round(abs($st - $edt) / 60,2). " minute";
echo "<br>";

echo $timediff=($edt-$st)/60;
```

Comment: What makes you think this would remotely work, or have anything to do with jQuery?

Comment: There is a link to the similar question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053057/doing-time-subtraction-with-jquery

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. You can't subtract strings like in your question.

```
a = new Date(2012, 1, 2, 21, 1, 3, 5)
b = new Date(2012, 2, 3, 22, 2, 3, 5)
c = a - b // diff in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

`'08:00 AM'` and `'03:00 PM'` are Strings, not numbers, and so they cannot be subtracted from one another.

You can find the difference in hours by using the date object to create the date of both times and subtract them.

Here are the parameters for the Date constructor:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

So

```
var start_d = new Date(0,0,0,8),
    end_d = new Date(0,0,0,11),
    diff = end_d - start_d;
```

Alternatively, you can use Date's methods to define the time

```
var start_d = new Date(), // makes a new date object of current time
    end_d = new Date(), // same
    diff;

start.setHours(8);
end.setHours(11);

diff = end_d - start_d;
```

This will return the difference in milliseconds, to convert to hours:

```
diff_hours = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60;
```

Comment: Fixed this question answer follow this link-: http://developermaliya.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/how-to-subtract-time-slot-in-jquery/